# Watir doesn't work in form in frame

Tags: ruby, forms, frame, watir

friends.
I am study ruby using watir for testing login in website AliExpress.com. I'd like to fill form automatically in https://login.aliexpress.com, but unfortunately for me. The website is using frame.
The form has html code:

```
<div id="login-content" class="form clr">
<dl>
<dt class="fm-label">
<div class="fm-label-wrap clr">
<span id="login-id-label-extra" class="fm-label-extra"></span>
<label for="fm-login-id">Account:</label>
</div>
</dt>
<dd id="fm-login-id-wrap" class="fm-field">
<div class="fm-field-wrap">
<div id="account-check-loading" class="loading-mask">
<div class="loading-icon"></div>
<div class="loading-mask-body"></div>
</div>
<input id="fm-login-id" class="fm-text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="Email address or member ID" tabindex="1" name="loginId">
</div>
```

my code: (ruby 2.1.5-p273, IE11)

```
require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "https://login.aliexpress.com"
b.div(id:"expressbuyerlogin", class:"iframe-show").exist? # => true
b.text_field(:name, "loginId").set "xxxxxxx@xxx.xx" # => Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["text", "password", "textarea"], :name=>"loginId"}
b.text_field(:name, "password").set "xxxxxxxxxxx" # => Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["text", "password", "textarea"], :name=>"password"}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frames are treated as separate browser contexts, so you have to specify which frame you are in. (for nested iframes, you would need to specify each one until you get to the desired context). In this case, your code should look like this:

```
require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "https://login.aliexpress.com"
b.iframe(id: 'alibaba-login-box').text_field(name: "loginId").set "xxxxxxx@xxx.xx"
b.iframe(id: 'alibaba-login-box').text_field(name: "password").set "xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Script works perfectly well with Firefox, but with IE 11 (Windows 7sp1) has mistake: WIN32OLERuntimeError: (in OLE method `document': ) OLE error code:80070005 in <Unknown>

Comment: Try using this: 
    ```require 'watir'
    Watir.driver = :webdriver```
or
    ```require 'watir-webdriver'```

Comment: The problem with IE11 has been solved using IEDriverServer_Win32 + require 'watir-webdriver'. All works perfectly well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you require 'watir' and specify IE, it uses watir-classic by default. It's an attempt to be backward compatible with watir 1.0 users, but anyone new coming to the project should be using watir-webdriver, and I think something will need to be done to make it less confusing as to what is going on.
Also, please accept this answer if it solved your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please add require 'watir-webdriver'
Also, make sure you are using the latest 'watir-webdriver' version and Watir version as 1.5.1.1145.

Comment: The problem with IE11 has been solved using IEDriverServer_Win32 + require 'watir-webdriver'. Thank you.